# read csv files in python

Tags: python, csv

I need to read one column from the multiple csv file present in folder and then extract minimum and maximum dates from the column.

For e.g. if i have folder path "/usr/abc/xyz/" and multiple csv files are present as below

```
aaa.csv
bbb.csv
ccc.csv
```

and the files are containing data

aaa.csv is containing the data

```
name,address,dates
xxx,11111,20190101
yyy,22222,20190201
zzz,33333,20190101
```

bbb.csv is containing the data

```
name,address,dates
fff,11111,20190301
ggg,22222,20190501
hhh,33333,20190601
```

so I need to extract the minimum and maximum dates from the files and in the above case the date range should be 20190101 to 20190601

Can anyone please help how can i extract the minimum and maximum dates from the files in python

I need to avoid pandas or any other package as I need to read csv files in directly in  pyhton

Comment: I suggest you look for a basic pandas tutorial, something like this should do: https://data36.com/pandas-tutorial-1-basics-reading-data-files-dataframes-data-selection/

Comment: i am not sure ,why downvoting this question.As,i already told in the question that i do not want to use pandas or any other package

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.read_csv('you_csv.csv')
print(max(dt['dates']))
print(min(dt['dates']))
```

If you need to avoid `pandas` you can do the following which is not recommended at all:

```
dt = []
with open('your_csv.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for row in data:
    dt.append(row.split(',')[2].rstrip())
dt.pop(0)
print(max(dt))
print(min(dt))
```

Comment: As ,i already mentioned that I do not want to use pandas etc. 
The second approach is doubtful as you are saying that it will read all the csv in a folder ?

Comment: @aspire Not at all. It reads the file as a string and splits the contents you want.

Answer (score 0):

A solution only using the available core libraries. It doesn't read the whole file into memory so should have a very low footprint and will work with larger files.

- `pathlib` is used to get all the csv files
- `datetime` is used to convert to dates
- `sys` is used for user input

```sh
$ python3 date_min_max.py /usr/abc/xyz/
min date: 2019-01-01 00:00:00
max date: 2019-06-01 00:00:00
```

*date_min_max.py*

```py
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
import sys


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    p = sys.argv[1]
else:
    p = "."

files = [x for x in Path(p).iterdir() if x.suffix == ".csv"]

date_format = "%Y%m%d"

dt_max = datetime.strptime("19000101", date_format)
dt_min = datetime.strptime("30000101", date_format)
for file in files:
    with file.open("r") as fh:
        for i, line in enumerate(fh):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            t = line.strip().split(",")[2]
            dt_max = max(dt_max, datetime.strptime(t, date_format))
            dt_min = min(dt_min, datetime.strptime(t, date_format))


print("min date: {}\nmax date: {}".format(dt_min, dt_max))
```